# `alert($('table tr').html());` displaying only one row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" > 
            $(function () {
                alert($('tr').html());
            })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>      
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I have a simple HTML table. In a JQuery script I tried to alert all rows in the table, but it alerts only one row of table. What does `$('tr')` actually return?

Why isn't it possible to display all the rows if `$('tr').css('background-color', 'red');` can change the colors of all?

Comment: Use `console.log` - why would you `alert` the entire HTML of all table rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** : Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

You could loop through all the rows using `each()` and use alert to display the html content :

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function () {
    $('tr').each(function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>      
  </tr>   
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the html for each tr and display the html in two alerts.
This will display your tr is two alert messages:

**SCRIPT**

```
 $(function () {
     $('tr').each(function() {
          alert($(this).html());
     });
 });
```

See working example at: https://jsfiddle.net/4qb4j6s1/1/

The reason `$('tr').css('background-color', 'red');` changes all tr's background color is because the jquery [function css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is applied to all instances on the of the element unless otherwise specified.  `Alert();` only displays the first instance of an html element!

In order to display the entire table in one alert you can do:

**SCRIPT**

```
alert($('table').html());
```